# Ruby on Rails SAAS Host And Monthly Cost Estimate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, saas

I´m trying to estimate the monthly cost involveld in a SAAS app Rails based. Is it calculated per bandwitch, database, space, or what? If so how much per user/month we will be charged? And what is the best SAAS solutions avaliable for Rails/Ajax like apps? We are an brazilian startup, based at Sao Paulo.

Sorry but i have no idea about how to calculate the monthly costs and i need that to our business plan.

The software will be an web app that helps teachers and students to share information in real time.

Thanks and sorry by my poor english!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount you pay for hosting generally depends on the needs of your application. I would recommend starting with a cloud hosting provider to give you the flexibility you might need early on. Cloud hosting is great because you can easily scale up and down to fit your needs. There may come a time where it makes sense to move to a dedicated server, but it won't happen over night.

As far as cloud hosting providers go, there are tons out there but these seem to be a few of the more popular ones. I personally use EngineYard and am happy with them, but each offers different pricing and options, so you will want to determine what your specific needs are first.

- [Heroku](http://heroku.com/)
- [EngineYard AppCloud](http://www.engineyard.com/products/appcloud)
- [Rackspace Cloud](http://www.rackspacecloud.com/index.php)

As far as including pricing in your business plan, I would recommend having a range, rather than a fixed monthly cost. Starting off with a low amount of traffic will cost less than $100/mo. As your needs change, this can go up into the thousands or higher.

Comment: Thanks man, you bet i´m going to try heroku asap. I will create an basic app and putting it online to learn the basic aspects and costs of the cloud host system.

Comment: Rackspace Cloud Sites no longer supports Rails applications.

Comment: For Heroku all their prices are fixed and easier to calculate. The first process ("dyno") is free, but after that they are $36/month prorated to the number of seconds used.  A 15GB shared db is an extra $15 per month. I would count on at least $60 for early development and (as recommended above) $100-$150 for a low traffic launch.  From there it scales as your traffic needs scale.